# how to highlight table cells in a certain way when hover over

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to highlight table cells with 'J' mark like this: [image]

In this picture I hover over a cell (the one that has a black border) and certain cells around it changes color. How to do this? I only can change a single cell, row or column.

```css
td {
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
tr:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}

tr:hover td {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And what about edge cases, such as hovering over the top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right cells?

Answer (score 3):

The solution that I am proposing using jQuery in order to link an event on every `td:hover`. By using `each`, `hover`, `Math.floor` and `toggleClass` you can easily achieve what you want to do.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#my-table td').each(function(index, elem){
    $("#" + elem.id).hover(function(){
      row_index = Math.floor((elem.id - 1) / 5);
      col_index = (elem.id - 1) % 5;
      
      right_cell_col = col_index + 1;
      top_cell_index = parseInt(elem.id) - 4;
      left_cell_col = col_index - 1;
      bottom_cell_index = parseInt(elem.id) + 5;
      
      if(left_cell_col >= 0) $("#" + (elem.id - 1)).toggleClass("colored");
      if(right_cell_col <= 4) {
        if (top_cell_index > 0) $("#" + top_cell_index).toggleClass("colored");
        $("#" + (parseInt(elem.id) + 1)).toggleClass("colored");
      }
      if(bottom_cell_index < 26) $("#" + bottom_cell_index).toggleClass("colored");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
td {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
td:hover {
    border-color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.colored {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my-table">
    <tr>
        <td id=1></td>
        <td id=2></td>
        <td id=3></td>
        <td id=4></td>
        <td id=5></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id=6></td>
        <td id=7></td>
        <td id=8></td>
        <td id=9></td>
        <td id=10></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id=11></td>
        <td id=12></td>
        <td id=13></td>
        <td id=14></td>
        <td id=15></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id=16></td>
        <td id=17></td>
        <td id=18></td>
        <td id=19></td>
        <td id=20></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id=21></td>
        <td id=22></td>
        <td id=23></td>
        <td id=24></td>
        <td id=25></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I see some inaccuracy when hovering over the 2x2 cells on the bottom-right corner.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    
    table td {
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    
    td {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 0;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: #fff;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    tr.hover {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #000;
    }
    /* tr:hover td {
            background-color: transparent;
        } */
    
    td.hover {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #000;
    }
    
    td.center {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #fff;
      outline: 2px red solid;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var HEIGHT = 5;
      var WIDTH = 5;
      $('td').hover(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        var table = self.parent().parent();

        var column = self.index();
        var row = self.parent().index();

        var current = table.find(`tr:eq(${row}) td:eq(${column})`)
        current.toggleClass('center')
        if (column > 0) {
          var before = table.find(`tr:eq(${row}) td:eq(${column - 1})`)
          before.toggleClass('hover');
        }

        if (row < HEIGHT - 1) {
          var bottom = table.find(`tr:eq(${row + 1}) td:eq(${column})`)
          bottom.toggleClass('hover');
        }
        if (column < WIDTH - 1) {
          var next = table.find(`tr:eq(${row}) td:eq(${column + 1})`)
          next.toggleClass('hover');
        }
        if (row > 0 && column < WIDTH - 1) {
          var nextUp = table.find(`tr:eq(${row - 1}) td:eq(${column + 1})`)
          nextUp.toggleClass('hover');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>

      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

How about using jquery?

Comment: Still doesn't work, the class stay attached on mouse out at some point

Comment: Ok now it works, but why using twice pretty much the same function? Why not using only toggleClass? It seems repetitive and when you see the same codes twice, refactor it, something is wrong. toggleClass will take care of your callback function

Comment: Ah, I feel that I have more helped you than the OP and I feel great with it as you seem pretty smart and good learner! My job is done here ;) Change it and I will upvote your great work.

Comment: Ok no problem, I did the change in order to remove my downvote. See what I did, by using toggleClass, it will reduce the code of the half